# Failing fast in a winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

In a .NET application, if I get a fatal exception (e.g. OOM), I failfast. I do this by calling Environment.Exit() which calls finally blocks (it may be Environment.Failfast() which calls finally blocks, I use whichever one does), in my applicationthreadexception event handler.

Is this the correct way of failing fast?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment.Failfast() does not run the finalizers, it puts an event in the Windows log and generates a minidump.  You don't want to fill the client's machine with minidumps, they are not small files.  And nobody is going to look at them.

Preventing finalizers on an OOM condition isn't very useful, finalizers are not going to allocate more memory.  Use Environment.Exit().  Or just don't catch anything, OOM is very hard to catch anyway since it can be thrown *anywhere*.  If you want to put effort into it then fix your code so it doesn't gobble so much memory.

Comment: Good answer. My Application isn't consuming too much memory, and there are no coding exceptions that I'd need such a catch block for, however. When you say hard to catch, what do you mean in specific?

Comment: Don't write code that you cannot test.  OOM can strike at *any* statement that uses the *new* operator.  You normally have a lot of them.  Which makes it uncatchable in practice.  You do *not* want to wrap every single one of them with try/catch, that's horrible.

Comment: But wouldn't they all propagate to a global catch (e.g. applicationthreadexception)?

Comment: Erm, I'm guessing you are talking about AppDomain.UnhandledException?  Not sure what you'd want to do there beyond logging the exception.